# how can i install root CA certification in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting the following error trying to install a root CA certificate in Apache JMeter:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you type in the message created for clarity purposes? It's easier to investigate in that way.

Comment: it's fine :) press OK. Jmeter creates a certificate it needs to work safely with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error at all, it's information message regarding JMeter created a self-signed SSL certificate.

Due to security reasons JMeter prints some information regarding the certificate so you could decide whether to accept it or not when you'll open a page over HTTPS protocol in browser.

So when browser prompts you whether to proceed to secure page using untrusted certificate or not - just double check certificate authority and if it matches what JMeter tells in that dialog - you're good to go.

References:

- **Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual page
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)